# How to configure exposed svc hostname IP address in Openshift 4.5

Tags: routes, openshift

How can I reconfigure the exposed CIDRs?

I know it is possible for Openshift 3.1 https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_router.html
in file /etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml, field
networkConfig:
externalIPNetworkCIDRs:

- <ip_address>/<cidr>

But I don't know on which node the file an be found and in Openshift 4.5 may be different.

I have exposed two services:
oc expose svc app1 and oc expose svc app2.
the hostname for the routes resolves the same IP address.
Probably there is only 1 IP address can be allocated.
So I try to find out how to configure the exposed CIDR.

Answer (score 1):

A big difference from 3.11 to 4.x is that ExternalIps are reconfigurable just patching the "networks.config" resource YAML.

You should set at least one from "spec.externalIP.policy" or "spec.externalIP.autoAssignCIDRs" (cluster-admin role is requested)
in 1st case, ExternalIp should be manually set in Service, in second case it is autoassigned.

> oc edit networks.config cluster

Than in your service, you can set:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
...
spec:
 ...
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.132.253
```

DOCS: [ExternalIP address block configuration][1]
[1]: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-externalip.html#nw-externalip-object_configuring-externalip